# How to get different values from multiple input field (React js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have a component;

```
    import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import cal from './image/bgimg.jpg'

function Home() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        semester: '',
        credit: '',
        sgpa: ''
    })
    const [noOfSem, setNoOfSem] = useState([])

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        let sems = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < state?.semester; index++) {
            sems.push(index + 1);
        }
        console.log(sems)
        setNoOfSem(sems);
    }
    const emptySemester=()=>{
        setState({...state,semester:''})
        setNoOfSem([])
    }
    const handleCgpaSubmit=()=>{
        console.log(state.credit,state.sgpa)
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <img src={cal} alt="" className='imgcal img-fluid' />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="col-md">
                        <div className="form1">
                            <div className="col-md formmain">
                                <input type="number" value={state?.semester} name='semester' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Enter Total Semester' />
                                {noOfSem.length===0?
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn333" onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
                                :
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn333" onClick={emptySemester}>Reset Semester</button>
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div className="col form2">
                                {noOfSem?.map((item, index) =>
                                    <>
                                        <div className="col-md seminpt">
                                            <label htmlFor="">Semester {index + 1}</label>
                                            <input type="Number" name='credit' value={state.credit} onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Total Credit' />
                                            <input type="Number" name='sgpa' value={state.sgpa} onChange={handleChange} placeholder={`SGPA sem${index + 1}`} />
                                        </div>
                                    </>
                                )}
                                {noOfSem.length>0 && 
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn3334" onClick={handleCgpaSubmit}>Submit</button>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Home
```

On the above component I have some dynamic input fields,Mentioned below:

```
    {
noOfSem?.map((item, index) =>
                                        <>
                                            <div className="col-md seminpt">
                                                <label htmlFor="">Semester {index + 1}</label>
                                                <input type="Number" name='credit' value={state.credit} onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Total Credit' />
                                                <input type="Number" name='sgpa' value={state.sgpa} onChange={handleChange} placeholder={`SGPA sem${index + 1}`} />
                                            </div>
                                        </>
                                    )}
```

My issue is "I want different data from each dynamic input field",How to achive this.

I want different input data in each dynamic field,but don't know what will be the process.I am getting same data in all field as given below screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPX7k.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is expected behavior since you use the same variable `state.credit` and `state.sgpa` for each `noOfSem` item. You could solve this problem by just add the index to the variable name or make it as an array.

Comment: how,plz give an example.

Comment: Here is example https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shannon-37ywlz?file=/src/App.js